# Scale an entire HTML element using CSS

Tags: html, css, scale, css-transforms, scaletransform

How can I scale an entire element and all children by a specific percentage or to a specific final size?

I have a `<table>`, and I am simulating a pictograph using JavaScript to calculate the width of divs + a repeating background tag. I'd like to have just one version of this logic, so scaling the parent table would solve this problem.

Comment: Is vw the solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/42399907/384316

Comment: Show some code or a demo of what you have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1. You can use CSS3 2D transforms:**

```
    div {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); /* Safari */
        transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    }
```

you only need to apply this to the parent element.

**2. You can use `zoom` but it has two disadvantages:**

- It's not a crossbrowser solution if you are using *positioning*
- It doesn't work on Firefox

example:

```
    div {
    zoom: 50%;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    }
```